# Apache Camel onException

Tags: java, apache, esb, onexception

I want to catch all Exception from routes.

I add this OnExeption :

```
onException(Exception.class).process(new MyFunctionFailureHandler()).stop();
```

Then, I create the class MyFunctionFailureHandler.

```
public class MyFunctionFailureHandler  implements Processor {

@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    Throwable caused;

    caused = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, Throwable.class);

    exchange.getContext().createProducerTemplate().send("mock:myerror", exchange);
   }

}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work and I don't know why.

if there is an Exception, the program must stop.

How can I know why this code doesn't work!!

Thanks.

Comment: I have to ask... Why not onException(Exception.class).to("mock:myerror")? Why use a processor only to forward to a different endpoint?

Answer (score 5):

I used this on my route:

```
public class MyCamelRoute extends RouteBuilder {

   @Override
   public void configure() throws Exception {

        from("jms:start")
           .process(testExcpProcessor)

       // -- Handle Exceptions
       .onException(Exception.class)
         .process(errorProcessor)
         .handled(true)

       .to("jms:start");
   }
}
```

and in my **errorProcessor**

```
public class ErrorProcessor implements Processor {

  @Override
  public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {


    Exception cause = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, Exception.class);

    if(cause != null){
        log.error("Error has occurred: ", cause);

        // Sending Error message to client
        exchange.getOut().setBody("Error");
    }else

        // Sending response message to client
        exchange.getOut().setBody("Good");
  }
}
```

I hope it helps

Comment: as of Camel 2.10, the onException needs to be specified at the top of the route and the onException clause needs to be ended with an end()

Answer (score 1):

keep in mind that if you have routes in multiple RouteBuilder classes, having an onExcpetion within this route will affect all routes under this RouteBuilder only

review this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283861/camel-exception-handling-doesnt-work-if-exception-clause-is-defined-in-a-separat)

additionally if an exception occurs within a route and handled inside this route,it won't be propagated to the original caller route you need to use noErrorHandler() i.e. `from(direct:start).errorHandler(noErrorHandler())` to propagate the exception handling back to the caller

Comment: If will not be propagated to the caller if it *wasn't* handled the in inner route, unless you use the workaround you described. But I never got the workaround working....